Run bash scripts on KDE Plasma sleep and wakeup events of Power Management as a particular user?
KDE Plasma 5.27.11 on Debian 12 amd64
I need to send some very short signals over USB on workstation's power management sleep and wake up events(not login and log out, they work fine). I have prepared separate bash scripts for those, only had no luck with finding how to bind them. I have root access to the machine so config solutions would work for me. How it can be done?

i created script in

/lib/systemd/system-sleep

and gave it executable flag
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
pre)
    /home/zzz/util/relay_off.sh
    ;;
esac

case "$1" in
post)
    /home/zzz/util/relay_on.sh
    ;;
esac

and it is working
